# Want to replace NULL values with Empty String

Tags: apex

I'm getting the values of a contact and generating an XML with respective Contact Details through Concatenation. Here, the problem is when contact fields doesn't have a value its displaying NULL. I want to replace it with EMPTY string. Is there any way ?

Comment: Where you are showing them, on Vforce page?

Comment: @Ashwani  I want to store the XML in Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apex, the you can simply check and replace them with null when you will show them like.

ex. if resultant variable is contact.field_name then you can simple change them:

```
contact.field_name = (contact.field_name != NULL ||  contact.field_name != 'NULL') ? contact.field_name : '';
```

if showing on visualforce page:

```
{!IF( OR(contact.field_name != null, contact.field_name != 'null'),contact.field_name, ''}
```

and if you get the xml as string then simply replace the complete string as:

```
String refinedString = xmlString.replace('NULL','');
```

but make sure your xml names don't contain 'null' combination anywhere except the value `null`

Comment: ThanQ @Ashwani.

Comment: But what if the value inside the string is actually a null (\x00)?